# Add enums to a list according to the value received back from database

Tags: c#, enums

How will I add enums to a list according to the value I get back from the database, If the value is 1 then add to the list else don't.

This is what I have more or less:

```
Permissions = new List<Permission>()
{
    ((int)data[0]["AllowOverride"] == 1 ? Permission.AllowOverride : "I do not have an else")
    ((int)data[0]["AllowAttachment"] == 1 ? Permission.AllowAttachment: "I do not have an else")
},
```

EDIT: I am constructing this list as part of an object initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the property based on the result of a lambda function, which negates the necessity of a separate function to construct the permissions. You can try something along the lines of:

```
Permissions = 
    new Func<DataRow, List<Permission>>(permissionData =>
    {
        List<Permission> permissions = new List<Permission>();
        // do all your if checks here to add the necessary permissions to the list
        return permissions;
    })(data[0])
```

EDIT: I just changed some variable names so it would actually compile without conflicting with your "data" variable already in use.

Answer (score 3):

No need for the conditional operator here, you simply use `if`:

```
Permissions = new List<Permission>();

if(((int)data[0]["AllowOverride"]) == 1)
    Permissions.Add(Permission.AllowOverride);

if(((int)data[0]["AllowAttachment"]) == 1)
    Permissions.Add(Permission.AllowAttachment);
```

Comment: It won't work because I am constructing the permission list as part of an object initializer.

Comment: Then don't do that. Or extract my code into a method and initialize the permission list like this: `Permissions = Method(data),`

Comment: I have to because it is part of a framework that I'm working on. The permissions property is part of about 30 odd properties on a bigger object that I am constructing.

Comment: @Ysterhak: I don't see how this forces you to use the object initializer. Anyway, you still have the option of extracting that code to a method as shown in my last comment